# with the following command sqoop job is running fine but while executing getting invalid username or password(both are correct)

Tags: oracle, passwords, hdfs, sqoop

#### Sqooping to HDFS from oracle DB

Job created successfully but while executing its showing an error invalid username or password.

```
sqoop job -Dmapred.job.queue.name=*** -Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class=org.apache.sqoop.util.password.CryptoFileLoader -Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.crypto.passphrase=*** --create jobname -- import --connect ************ --password-file file:///tmp/pass.enc --username *** --table *** --check-column *** --incremental append --last-value *** --target-dir **** --split-by **** --verbose

sqoop job --exec jobname
```

> Error:invalid username/password; login denied

Comment: check the permission of password file. Read permission should be given to user from which you are running this job.

Comment: Can you give complete error stack?